# partition count reduced at sink during kafka stream record forward

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka stream for processing few kafka records , I have two node one is for doing some transformation and other is a final sink.

My the topics are INTER_TOPIC and FINAL_TOPIC are having 20 partitions each. and my producer which writing to INTER_TOPIC is writing in key value and partition-er is round robin.

below is the code at my inter transform node.

```
public void streamHandler() {

        Properties props = getKafkaProperties();

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> processStream = builder.stream("INTER_TOPIC",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        //processStream.peek((key,value)->System.out.println("key :"+key+" value :"+value));

        processStream.map((key, value) -> getTransformer().transform(key, value)).filter((key,value)->filteroutFailedRequest(key,value)).to("FINAL_TOPIC", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));


        KafkaStreams IStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);

        IStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throw-able e) {

                logger.error("Thread Name :" + t.getName() + " Error while processing:", e);
            }
        });

        IStreams.cleanUp();
        IStreams.start();

        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            logger.error("Failed streaming ",e);
        }
    }
```

but my sink is getting data in 2 partitions only, but I have 20 stream thread configured, and I verified  my producer is writing to all 20 partitions, How to know that my transform node forwarding to all 20 partitions of my FINAL_TOPIC

```
30 Sep 2019 10:39:41,416 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-3] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:39:41,416 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-4] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:39:41,416 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-3] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:39:41,416 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-4] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:40:57,427 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-3] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:40:57,427 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-4] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:40:57,427 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-3] Received
30 Sep 2019 10:40:57,427 INFO  c.j.m.s.StreamHandler [289] [streams-user-61a77203-9afc-4c66-843d-94c20a509793-StreamThread-4] Received
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and partition-er is round robin

Why do you think that the partitioner is round-robin? By default, Kafka Streams applies a hash-based partitioning based on the key.

If you want to change the default partitioner, you can implement interface `StreamPartitioner` and pass it via:

```java
Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())
        .withStreamPartitioner(...)
```

Comment: In that case how to enable or add customized partitin-er ?

Comment: Updated my answer -- you can pass a custom partitioner via `Produced`.

Comment: props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomPartitioner.class); ... will this also work? There is a bit of this code added

Comment: Could you point to some example on how to write withStreamPartitioner(...) ?

Comment: Maybe the default implementation helps (don't know any other example): https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/DefaultStreamPartitioner.java